# How to enable GPS or show location service popup using javascipt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, gps, location-services

I want to show an enable location service popup, just like Google Map shows it in the mobile web browser when GPS is off in mobile settings. I would like to use only javascript or jQuery, not android or Phonegap.

Would it even be possible with javascript or jQuery? Does anyone have some advice for me?

Comment: Unless the browser app offers to turn on GPS for you when JS code on a page requests the location, there's no way to do this.

Comment: @ChrisG but how google map show location service popup in any mobile browser

Comment: My guess is you just use `navigator.geolocation` in your JS code and the browser takes care of the rest.

Comment: @ChrisG I am already using navigator.geolocation it only work when GPS is turned on and it is working fine. But I need for a case when GPS is off and I need a popup just like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzYqt.png
to enable GPS

Comment: Is this the popup from the Google Maps app? If so, you would need to create an actual app, as opposed to a website. If not, where exactly is this popup from? What browser and what website? If this is indeed the google maps website, I cannot check what my phone does because any maps link is sent to the app.

Comment: I turned off the default handling and google.com/maps simply says it couldn't determine my exact location

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible with Browser's Geolocation API. Look at following example -

**Note: ** Geolocation API does not works as stackoverflow's code snippet. Try to run this example locally in your machine.

```js
function geoFindMe() {

  const status = document.querySelector('#status');
  const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

  mapLink.href = '';
  mapLink.textContent = '';

  function success(position) {
    const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    status.textContent = '';
    mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
    mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;
  }

  function error() {
    status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
  }

  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'Locating…';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }

}

document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
```

```html
<button id = "find-me">Show my location</button><br/>
<p id = "status"></p>
<a id = "map-link" target="_blank"></a>
```

Learn more about [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)

Comment: thank you for your help but this is not what I am looking for. I need something like this i.stack.imgur.com/MzYqt.png Need to show popup where it can redirect to your mobile setting to enable GPS.